# Report viewer com parametros. C#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Olá!

O relatório (.rdlc) está retornando com sucesso dados com a ajuda de um `datatable`, porém preciso colocar parâmetros e não funciona.

Segue o código:

```
 private void frmReportTeste_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dsOrcPrevisto.dtOrcPrevisto' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.dtOrcPrevistoTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsOrcPrevisto.dtOrcPrevisto);

            ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("op.venda", venda.ToString());
            ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("op.vendedor", vendedor.ToString());
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2 });

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Exibe o erro:

> Message = "Tentativa de configurar um parâmetro de relatório 'op.venda' que não está definido neste relatório."

Pelo que entendi, op.venda não está no `sql` que preenche o `datatable` mas está sim.

Comment: no editor do .rdlc você tem q adicionar os parâmetros que você está passando.

Comment: adicionei uma tabela vinculada ao `datatable`, mas não achei a parte dos parametros

Comment: Eu gosto bastante do report builder para construir relatórios, ele é bem fácil. Basicamente você deve definir um datasource, podendo ser uma conexão direta com o banco de dados ou um arquivo xml que é o seu caso, depois você deve definir um dataset, vincular o datasource ao dataset e criar os fields que receberão os parâmetros.

Comment: e os parametros no report builder são colocados aonde?

Comment: para colocar parametros é na hora de criar o table adapter.. na hora que cria a query tem que colocar os parametros na propria query.. Exemplo: `where cliente = @cliente`... se for oracle é `:cliente`